# Which question is grammatically correct?

Tags: questions, countability

I'm not a native speaker, which of these is grammatically correct?

- "**How many** amounts of information?"
- "**How many** pieces of information?"
- "**How many** information?"
- "**How much** information?"

I think the 2nd and 4th ones are correct and the others aren't, am I correct?

I do understand that many is used with countable nouns and much is used to uncountable nouns.

And I also understand that the word "information" is an uncoutable noun in British English.

What confuses me is an exercise for school:

> How much information do you need? (**use how many**)

One of my friends said it'd be like the first example but I don't think so.

Comment: Welcome. We cannot really answer your question unless you can demonstrate your own understanding of the difference between *many* and *much* and why these examples confuse you. If the question is about the South Asian use of *information* as a countable noun, which is not accepted in British or American English, see *[If a word is coined / popularized / used only or mainly by second-language speakers of English, is it still considered to be an English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169468/)*

Comment: "Information" is an uncountable noun, so "many information" is not correct.   Similarly "amount" is uncountable, so "many amounts" is also not correct.  Since this is basic grammar, this question may be removed unless you can add more detail why this is particularly confusing to you.

Comment: @Andrew but according to Longman dictionary "Amount" is countable, that confuses me.

Comment: @Andrew And also according to this answer on the website, it's countable. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/254372/232158

Comment: @NabilTharwat  true, to be fair "amount" is one of those nutty English words that is often plural (*amounts*) but still used as an uncountable noun. "The bank recently transferred several large amounts of money".  Maybe it's best to think of it as an irregular that's usually (but not always) uncountable.

Comment: @Andrew Just to settle this up and clear my head of confusion, is the first example wrong?

Comment: @NabilTharwat  *technically*, it's not wrong.  But it doesn't sound like natural English.

Comment: @Andrew Well this explains my confusion. Thanks for your effort! ^^

Comment: @NabilTharwat  Yeah now that you explain it, I can see the difficulty.  Let me write this up as an answer.

Comment: These aren’t full sentences, so, technically, **none** of them are “grammatically correct."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of **information** as if it were **honey**, the sweet substance bees produce, not the synonym for "nice person" or "sweetheart". Also think of it in its flowing state, not crystallized.

How many honey does the recipe call for? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

How much honey does the recipe call for? <sup>grammatical</sup>

How many informations on your web browsing habits does Google collect? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

How much information on your web browsing habits does Google collect? <sup>grammatical</sup>

An **amount** is an unspecified quantity.  For that reason we cannot ask *How many amounts...?* because nobody knows the size of the amount. And when you add amounts together, they simply become a larger amount. An amount has no size until it is modified, for example "a small amount" or "a large amount", and even then the size is relative and vague.

Answer (score 1):

"Information" is uncountable (we would never say the plural "informations") so "many information" is not correct.  "Much information" or "a large amount of information" is better.

"Amount" seems to be one of those quirky English words that defies easy categorization.  Most often it is *uncountable*, even if plural:

> I received a large **amount** of money from an inheritance.
>
> The bank recently transferred a number of suspiciously large **amounts** of money.

It's quirky because while you might speak of multiple "amounts" of something, if you were to physically *count* the amounts, you would either combine them or use a more descriptive quantifier.

> We found those previously mentioned "large amounts of money" all in a single warehouse, stacked up in numerous *piles*.

So perhaps it's best to think of "amount" as an irregular noun that's usually, but not always, uncountable.  To answer your question, "How many amounts of information?" is not *technically* wrong, but it does not sound like natural English.